# Dual of $\mathbb Z^I$ for uncountable $I$

Tags: gr.group-theory, ac.commutative-algebra

> Let $I$ be an infinite set. There is a homomorphism of abelian groups $\mathbb{Z}^{(I)} \to \hom(\mathbb{Z}^I,\mathbb{Z})$ which sends the basis element $e_i$ to the projection $p_i$. If $I$ is countable, it's a famous result of Specker<sup>1</sup> that this is actually an isomorphism. But what happens when $I$ is uncountable?

Clearly it is injective. Surjectivity means that $\phi \in \hom(\mathbb{Z}^I,\mathbb{Z})$ is determined by the values $\phi(e_i)$ and that these values vanisch for almost all $i$. I can't copy the proof for the countable case.

<sup>1</sup> Ernst Specker, Additive Gruppe von Folgen ganzer Zahlen, Portugaliae Math. 9 (1950), 131-140. [MR0039719](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR0039719) (12,587b)

Comment: Related qn, when I is countable .. http://mathoverflow.net/questions/10239/ 

Comment: To address the question in the title: The $\mathbb{Z}$-dual of $\mathbb{Z}^I$ is the free abelian group whose rank equals the cardinality of the set $D$ of all countably complete ultrafilters on $I$. Moreover, $|I| \le |D|$ and if the cardinality of $I$ is less than the first measurable cardinal, then $|I|=|D|$. For references see my answer to this question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/132073/homomorphisms-from-powers-of-z-to-z 

Comment: Reposting the link mentioned in a previous [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/20584) so that it appears in the "Linked" questions list: [Is it true that, as $\Bbb Z$-modules, the polynomial ring and the power series ring over integers are dual to each other?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/10239)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With regard to Mariano's answer, I believe some clarification is in order. A closely related question was asked by Michael Barr and answered by user Ralph [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/132073/homomorphisms-from-powers-of-z-to-z/132083#132083). In brief, the homomorphism named in Martin's question is in fact an isomorphism, provided that $I$ has cardinality less than the first measurable cardinal.

Shelah and Strüngmann (accessible [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0009045v1.pdf)) refer to this result as well, using the same source given by Ralph, just before Definition 2.1:

> For generalizations to products of larger cardinalities and the resulting definition of slenderness for abelian groups we refer to [EM] or [F1]

where [EM] is the text by Eklof and Mekler. It seems that Shelah and Strüngmann are talking about something slightly different: homomorphisms out of *free complete products* (but using a notation which could unfortunately suggest direct products).